# jQuery slideDown on newly appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery `slideDown()` effect on my new appended `<div>`'s.

Here is my Javascript code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/loadmore/dj/",
    data: {
        'slug': $('.dj_slug').text().trim(),
        'song_rank': $("#dj_song_list").find('.song_block').length
    },
}).done(function (response) {
    $('#dj_song_list').append(response).hide().slideDown(1000);
});
```

This works but the `slideDown()` is applied to the entire `#dj_song_list` and not just the appended `<div>`'s. How can I apply it to just the newly appended `<div>`'s?

Here is my HTML structure for reference

```
<div id='dj_song_list'>
    {% include 'hunt/songs_dj.html' %}
</div>
```

songs_dj.html

```
<div class="song_block">
    ...
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/loadmore/dj/",
    data: {
        'slug': $('.dj_slug').text().trim(),
        'song_rank': $("#dj_song_list").find('.song_block').length
    },
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function (response) {
    $(response).appendTo($('#dj_song_list')).hide().slideDown(1000);
});
```

Comment: What is type of response in this case? I thought it would be a string. I thought that would be string and if this is the case how are you calling jQuery methods on a string ?

Comment: It throws `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. The response is HTML `<div>`'s

Comment: @MikeWu You're perfectly correct, I need to make it a "jQuery element". Answer updated.

Comment: @Niklas It now throws this error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div itemprop="track" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording" class="song_block">
 <div class="song-title">
  <span class="song_rank">11</span> <span itemprop="name">Never Say Goo...<omitted>...v> `

Comment: I added `dataType: 'html'` to the call, telling jQuery that it should return a HTML string, not try to guess what is being returned. Maybe jQuery tried interpreter it as something else.

Comment: Could you post an example of what `response` returns? The entire string that is.

Comment: @Niklas 10 `<div>`'s. Something like 
`<div class="song_block">
    ...
    ...
    ...
</div>`

Comment: Weird, it should work. No difference adding the response string to `$(response)` than to `$('#dj_song_list').append(response)`.

Comment: @Niklas I just figured it out. Apparently jQuery 1.9 doesn't recognise HTML strings that do not start with `<`. Read more - http://stage.jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring

Comment: @YinYang What did your start with then, a space? Good you found that, I'm was starting to lose my faith on the world... haha. Then we learnt something today as well!

Comment: @Niklas Haha, same here, I had almost given up. I was importing some template tags in the first few lines so those got replaced with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7cws8/1/

I have done exactly what you want:

Also for your code you can append response to a hidden div and then can slide it down:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/loadmore/dj/",
    data: {
        'slug': $('.dj_slug').text().trim(),
        'song_rank': $("#dj_song_list").find('.song_block').length
    },
}).done(function (response) {
    $('#dj_song_list').append("<div id='response-content' style='display:none;'>"+response+"</div>");

$("#response-content").slideDown(1000);

});
```

Comment: This works only the 1st time I click the load more button. The 2nd time, no `<div>`'s are appended.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 $('#dj_song_list').append(response).hide().slideDown(1000);
```

Into this:

```
 $('#dj_song_list').append(response);
 $('#dj_song_list').find('div').last().hide().slideDown(1000);
```

Comment: The response consists of 10 `<div>`'s. This makes it apply to only the last `<div>`. Is there any way to make it apply to the last 10, instead of last?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. This is what I used.

`$('#dj_song_list').find('.song_block').slice(-10).hide().slideDown(1000);`